# PIVOT problem when converting 4 Rows (1 Column) to 5 Columns (1 Row)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have a table var with some rows but only one column of type DATETIME, like this:

```
[Day]
2010-08-03
2010-08-04
2010-08-10
2010-08-11
```

I need to show on some columns but in only one row.
My result set will be limited to 5 rows, then I can limit to 5 columns too.
Example of what I need:

```
[Day1]      [Day2]      [Day3]      [Day4]      [Day5]
2010-08-03  2010-08-04  2010-08-10  2010-08-11  NULL
```

I was trying to do it using PIVOT in SQL Server 2005.
But all examples uses more columns to agregate values, then I'm not understanding.

This is the query I was trying:

```
SELECT r.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Day ASC) Line, Day FROM @MyDays) AS o
PIVOT (MIN(Line) FOR Day IN (Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4, Day5)) AS r
```

But the result is all NULL:

```
[Day1]  [Day2]  [Day3]  [Day4]  [Day5]
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Row_Number()` just returns a number in the list 1-5 so it isn't going to match anything in your list "Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4, Day5". I have appended "Day" onto the front so it will.

Additionally you have `MIN(Line) FOR Day IN`, This needs to be the otherway around. It is the value of `Day` that you are wanting to display.

```
;with mydays as
(

SELECT '2010-08-03' AS [Day] UNION
SELECT '2010-08-04' AS [Day] UNION
SELECT '2010-08-10' AS [Day] UNION
SELECT '2010-08-11' AS [Day] 
)
SELECT r.* FROM (
   SELECT 
      'Day' + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Day ASC)as varchar(10)) Line, 
       Day 
   FROM mydays) AS o
PIVOT (MIN([Day]) FOR Line IN (Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4, Day5)) AS r
```

Comment: Now I understood: the values in the rows should be the same as the column names I want. Thank you, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution which does not involve the Pivot statement:

```
With RawData As
    (
    Select '2010-08-03' AS [Day]
    Union All Select '2010-08-04' 
    Union All Select '2010-08-10'
    Union All Select '2010-08-11'
    )
    , NumberedItems As
    (
    Select Day, Row_Number() Over( Order By Day ) As Line
    From RawData
    )
Select Min ( Case When Line = 1 Then [Day] End ) As Day1
    , Min ( Case When Line = 2 Then [Day] End ) As Day2
    , Min ( Case When Line = 3 Then [Day] End ) As Day3
    , Min ( Case When Line = 4 Then [Day] End ) As Day4
    , Min ( Case When Line = 5 Then [Day] End ) As Day5
From NumberedItems
```

Comment: Very interesting, but I think that the syntax with PIVOT is more easy to read. Is there any considerable performance gain when not using PIVOT?